# Strange behaviour with add_{$meta_type}_metadata | add_post_metadata filter

Tags: hooks, filters

I'm unsuccesfully trying to use the add_{$meta_type}_metadata. This filter is called inside add_metadata function (wp-includes/meta.php:31 in Wordpress 3.4.2).
In particular I wanna hook "add_post_metadata" filter among others. My target is to execute custom code to add,update,get custom meta, so I don't break wordpress way to do things.

body of function add_metadata

```
     function add_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique =    false) {
[...]
$check = apply_filters( "add_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key,     
$meta_value, $unique );
if ( null !== $check )
    return $check;

 [...]
```

$ckeck after filter execution should contain the value I return from the function "filter_negozi_add_metadata"

This is the code I use (inside my plugin):

```
 add_action('init', array('my_plugin','init'));
class my_plugin
{
 const META_KEY='my_plugin_key';
public static function init()
{
    new self();
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->add_filters();
}

protected function add_filters()
{       
///function below works
add_filter('get_post_metadata',array(&$this,'filter_negozi_get_metadata'),10,4);
//the one below instead doesn't work 
$ret=add_filter('add_post_metadata',array(&$this,'filter_negozi_add_metadata'),10,5);
//$ret contains true so add_filter works correctly
}
public function filter_negozi_add_metadata($foo=null,$object_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique )
{
    if($meta_key==self::META_KEY)
    {
$ret='foo';
    }
    return $ret;
}

}
```

The really strange fact is that global $wp_filter doesn't contain my function even if $ret is true.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution...
I have had to call add_filter outside my plugin class, because of Wordpress hooks priority.
With the actual code, I call add_filter after the 'init' event, that's probably too late.
If I move this line of code:

```
 add_filter('add_post_metadata',array(&$this,'filter_negozi_add_metadata'),10,5);
```

on top of the file, the hook works like expected.
So to recap, this is the wroking code:

```
 add_action('init', array('my_plugin','init'));
 //filter goes here
 add_filter('add_post_metadata',array('my_plugin','filter_negozi_add_metadata'),10,5);

class my_plugin
{
 const META_KEY='my_plugin_key';
public static function init()
{
    new self();
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->add_filters();
}

protected function add_filters()
{       
add_filter('get_post_metadata',array(&$this,'filter_negozi_get_metadata'),10,4);


}
public static function filter_negozi_add_metadata($foo=null,$object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique )
{
    //if condition doesn't match return a null value to allow wordpress to behave in the standard way
    $ret=null;
    if($meta_key==self::META_KEY)
    {
        $ret='foo';
    }
    return $ret;
}

}
```